# ncmpcpp character problem

Tags: terminal, xfce, mpd

This was really wired! All `=` became `q` on my xfce4-terminal app, what's wrong with it?

Any ideas?

[image]

```
%> set | grep LANG
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=en_US.utf8
```

Comment: What does `set | grep LANG` say?

Comment: @jippie updated

Comment: Does it happen only in xfce4-terminal or on other X terminal emulators as well?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this only happens in `ncmpcpp`. Does your build of `ncmpcpp` support charset detection? See output of `ncmpcpp --version`. If this is not the case, try setting the following option in `~/.ncmpcpp/config`:

```
system_encoding = <your_encoding_here>
```

And in `~/.mpdconf`:

```
filesystem_charset "<your_encoding_here>"
```

Also make sure your `xfce4-terminal` matches this same encoding.

Answer (score 0):

On a Raspberry Pi, this worked for me to fix the problem: export LC_ALL=en_GB.utf8

Comment: Would you know _why_ this fixes it?  And would it most likely fix it for the user in the question too?